# Ispell and its process have different character maps

Tags: emacs

I've just started getting this error with emacs on my Macbook Pro:

```
Ispell and its process have different character maps
```

I've tried changing my character map to utf-8. No luck. It would be nice if it told me how they were different and what to do about it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coding of the buffer is not specified, EMACS attempts to determining automatically. This causes a problem if the buffer contains a UTF-8 or Latin1 character and the subprocess is determined to be sending up ASCII.

I have solved the problem by placing this line as the first line of my `.tex` files:

```
% -*-mode: LaTeX; coding: us-ascii;-*-
```

Comment: My buffer is only us-ascii (I searched for [^[:ascii:]]) but I still get the "*Ispell and its process have different character maps*" message. How can I find out what character map ispell actually uses on my machine?

Comment: Look at the environment of the ispell process. You are probably setting the encoding in the `LC_ALL` or `LANG` environment variables.

Comment: I should add that your buffer only having us-ascii characters doesn't mean that it has us-ascii encoding. It could have LATIN1 encoding or UTF8 encoding, since both are proper supersets of us-ascii.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error message. In my case, the solution was to due to misalignment with the localwords appended in the bottom. There was a '%' in the localwords that needed to be on a newline.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a find and replace, I accidentally inserted a '-' into a word in the LocalWords list.  Removing the dash fixed the problem